# Logstash, elasticsearch, Kibana, include IP

Tags: redis, elasticsearch, logstash, indexer, kibana

I have a redis server, logstash indexer server, and an elasticsearch server.
How can I have the indexer server or even the shipper servers include the IPs in the log so that it's easier to sort in Kibana?
Or is this something that is done in the elasticsearch config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your input log to logstash, logstash will create an event and add **hostname** to the event. Logstash use hostname instead of IP because one server will have several IP. For example, 127.0.0.1, public IP etc. therefore it doesn't know which IP to use. So logstash use hostname.

Comment: Thanks. I can use the DNS filter after that, correct? If so, how would I do this?

Comment: Oh wait, I did it. filter {
   dns {
      add_field => [ "Logs, from %{host}" ]
      type => [ "MESSAGES" ]
      resolve => [ "host" ]
      action => [ "replace" ]
     }
}

Answer (score 2):

Did it. I added this:

```
filter {
   dns {
      add_field => [ "IPs", "Logs, from %{host}" ]
     }
}

filter {
   dns {
      type => [ "MESSAGES" ]
      resolve => [ "host" ]
      action => [ "replace" ]
     }
}
```

Reason why I used  a double filter was so that I still was able to keep the hostname after "replace" overwrote the host value to the IP address.

Comment: Congratulation. If you have any problem, come and ask at stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm curious if I can have the shipper do the DNS part instead of the indexer. This is because I'm using AWS and auto-scaling so the IPs will always change

Comment: Yes. You can do at shipper.

Comment: How would I do this? Currently I have this in my shipper: filter {
      dns {
      type => [ "MESSAGES" ]
      resolve => [ "host" ]
      action => [ "replace" ]
     }
}
The problem is that this requires the /etc/hosts file to be updated. I guess there's no way around that. I'd like it to send both the IP AND the hostname. I know the filter is overriding it but is there a way to get the hostname in there before the override?

Comment: ooh, I did it. Changed replace with append. Yay. Now to get around the /etc/hosts issue

Comment: Is there a way to get the IP without having to update /etc/hosts?